# String is palindrome or not

Tags: java, string

I need to check whether a string is a palindrome, but I'm always getting "not palindrome". What's my mistake?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String st = "iti";
    StringBuffer st1 =new StringBuffer(st);
    st1.reverse();
    System.out.println(st1);
    System.out.print(st.equals(st1));
    if(st1.equals(st)==true) {
        System.out.print("palindrome string");
    } else {
        System.out.print("not palindrome");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to call toString() on the StringBuffer. StringBuffer != String

Comment: FYI, `== true` is always redundant.

Answer (score 2):

A `StringBuffer` is not a `String`, thus it will never be equal to a `String`. Compare `st` with `st1.toString()` instead.

As an aside, in `if(st1.equals(st)==true)` comparing a boolean with `true` is not necessary and error-prone. You should write it as `if(st1.toString().equals(st))` so you don't use a single `=` by mistake and introduce a bug that can be rather hard to notice.

```
class Palindrome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String st = "iti";
        StringBuffer st1 =new StringBuffer(st);
        st1.reverse();
        if(st1.toString().equals(st)) { // HERE notice the use of `toString`
            System.out.print("palindrome string");
        } else {
            System.out.print("not palindrome");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String st = "iti";
StringBuffer st1 =new StringBuffer(st);
st1.reverse();
System.out.println(st1);
System.out.println(st.equals(st1));
if(st.equals(""+st1)) { // convert st1 from StringBuffer to String
    System.out.print("palindrome string");
} else {
    System.out.print("not palindrome");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To derive the *String* value within *StringBuffer*, you need to call the *toString* method.

```java
System.out.print(st.equals(st1.toString()));
```

And, at your *if-conditional* statement.

```java
if(st1.toString().equals(st)==true)
```